# validate inputs with default values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation, jquery-validate

Question:
How do i validate default values that set into the inputs?
I mean i want to ignore the default values and if the user haven't inserted any different value , the validation will alert him that he haven't inserted any thing.
Model:

```
public class ContactUsViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please enter full name")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "enter email")]
    [Email(ErrorMessage = "enter email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "enter phonenumber")]
    [Mobile(ErrorMessage = "enter phonenumber")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please address the issue")]
    public string Issue { get; set; }

        public IDictionary<string, object> FullNameProperties
        {
            get
            {
                return new Dictionary<string, object>()
                             {
                                 {"Value", "FullName"}
                             };
            }
        }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="ui-contact-us-form">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Contact","Home",FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="FullName" class="form-ui-icon-name ui-block-inline"></label>
                <div class="input-black">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ContactUsViewModel.FullName, Model.ContactUsViewModel.FullNameProperties)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ContactUsViewModel.FullName)
                </div>  
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="PhoneNumber" class="form-ui-icon-phone ui-block-inline"></label>
                <div class="input-black">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ContactUsViewModel.PhoneNumber, Model.ContactUsViewModel.PhoneNumber)
                </div> 
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="Email" class="form-ui-icon-email ui-block-inline"></label>
                <div class="input-black">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ContactUsViewModel.Email, Model.ContactUsViewModel.EmailProperties)
                    <input type="text" value="מייל" name="Email"/>
                </div> 
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="Issue" class="form-ui-icon-pen ui-block-inline"></label>
                <div class="input-black">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ContactUsViewModel.Issue, Model.ContactUsViewModel.IssueProperties)
                </div> 
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="spacer"></div> 

        <div class="ui-text-area">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.ContactUsViewModel.Notes)
        </div>
        <div class="spacer"></div> 

        <div class="form-ui-btn">
            <input type="submit" value="" />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> There is more than one potential solution to this.
>
> Probably the simplest solution is to set your default value to placeholder attribute instead of value attribute of the input element:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SomeField, new { id = "someFieldId", placeholder = "DefaultVal"})
```

> Which yields the following HTML:

```html
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="required" id="someFieldId" name="SomeField" placeholder="DefaultVal" value="">
```

> RegularExpression Validation on Model:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(?!.*DefaultVal).*$", ErrorMessage = "invalid")]
```

> If you must use the value attribute on your input element, This regular expression does a negative lookahead to consider ANY value EXCEPT the literal "DefaultVal" as valid. That being said, this soultion requires you to choose a default value that should never be expected as an actual input from the user.
>
> Coupled with the [REQUIRED] attribute users can input any value except the "DefaultVal", null or empty.